# RobotFramework AutoIT NotePad Test Passes but doesnt launch Notepad

Tags: robotframework, autoit

I have this very simple robot script to launch notepad.exe and type some text. The Test passes, but it doesnt launch notepad.

I am using Windows 10, python 3.7.1 and here are my versions of python packages:

```
Appium-Python-Client==0.31
decorator==4.3.0
docutils==0.14
kitchen==1.2.5
Pillow==5.4.1
pywin32==224
robotframework==3.0.4
robotframework-appiumlibrary==1.5.0.1
robotframework-autoitlibrary==1.2.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary==3.2.0
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.11.0
urllib3==1.24.1
```

My robot scripts reads like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           AutoItLibrary


*** Test Cases ***
AutoIT Notepad Test
    Run    notepad.exe
    Wait For Active Window    Untitled - Notepad
    Send    This is some text
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I removed the Run notepad.exe step, launch notepad manually, then this script works. I am new to autoit can someone please tell me whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

If you have notepad in the default location, try this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    AutoItLibrary

*** Variables ***
${notepad}    C:\\Program Files\\Notepad\\notepad.exe

*** Test Cases ***
Run     ${notepad}
Send    This is some text
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The test was passing be notepad was getting launched in a hidden window. I gave it the addtional argument and it passed:

```
*** Test Cases ***
AutoIT Notepad Test
    Run    notepad.exe    ${EMPTY}     1
    Wait for active window    Untitled - Notepad
    Send   Typing some text
```